# list index out of range while list is full

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing

When I execute this code:

```
import random
list1 = ['afgdddd', 'bcbvnbn', 'casretb', 'dbcbv ', 'egfhsgs']
list2 = ['a5y5546', 'brtewtwret', 'chrtyey', 'dqawtet', 'egreg']
choice1 = random.randint(0, len(list1))
print(list1[choice1])
print(list2[choice1])
```

Sometimes a get this error:

> python IndexError: list index out of range

What is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valid list indices for a list of length 5 are 0,1,2,3,4. You are choosing a random number from 0,1,2,3,4,5. When the random number is 5 your index is out of range just as the error message says.

To prevent this from occurring you need a random number between 0 and 4. Simply change to:

```
choice1 = random.randint(0, len(list1) - 1)
```

Subtracting 1 from the length of a list is a very common pattern to get the last element in an array.

To debug something like this yourself, you should `print(choice1)` before trying to `print(list1[choice1])` to see why the index may be out of range.

Comment: is there any way to prevent this error from happening?

Comment: the lists that i will use will have the excact same lengt.